# flat XML to nested using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

Been spending too much time on this.."f$%"
Hope you can share of your experience.
I have the source flat XML arriving from external db in the following structure:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ns:MT_ActualCosts xmlns:ns="http://percite:scmaster/actual_costs">
        <row>
            <EVENT_ID>106</EVENT_ID>
            <LINE_NUMBER>0</LINE_NUMBER>
            <INVOICE_NUMBER>9999</INVOICE_NUMBER>
            <INVOICE_DATE>2015-02-09 00:00:00.0</INVOICE_DATE>
            <CURRENCY_CODE>USD</CURRENCY_CODE>
            <TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>0001</TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>
            <RO_NUMBER>102808</RO_NUMBER>
        </row>
        <row>
            <EVENT_ID>106</EVENT_ID>
            <LINE_NUMBER>1</LINE_NUMBER>
            <INVOICE_NUMBER>24444</INVOICE_NUMBER>
            <PLANT>0003</PLANT>
            <ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>122</ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>
        </row>
        <row>
            <EVENT_ID>109</EVENT_ID>
            <LINE_NUMBER>0</LINE_NUMBER>
            <INVOICE_NUMBER>24458</INVOICE_NUMBER>
            <INVOICE_DATE>2015-02-09 00:00:00.0</INVOICE_DATE>
            <CURRENCY_CODE>USD</CURRENCY_CODE>
            <TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>0011</TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>
            <RO_NUMBER>102813</RO_NUMBER>
        </row>
        <row>
            <EVENT_ID>109</EVENT_ID>
            <LINE_NUMBER>1</LINE_NUMBER>
            <INVOICE_NUMBER>24458</INVOICE_NUMBER>
            <PLANT>0003</PLANT>
            <ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>11.1</ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>
        </row>
        <row>
            <EVENT_ID>108</EVENT_ID>
            <LINE_NUMBER>0</LINE_NUMBER>
            <INVOICE_NUMBER>24535</INVOICE_NUMBER>
            <INVOICE_DATE>2015-02-19 00:00:00.0</INVOICE_DATE>
            <CURRENCY_CODE>USD</CURRENCY_CODE>
            <TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>11</TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>
            <RO_NUMBER>102811</RO_NUMBER>
        </row>
        <row>
            <EVENT_ID>108</EVENT_ID>
            <LINE_NUMBER>1</LINE_NUMBER>
            <INVOICE_NUMBER>24535</INVOICE_NUMBER>
            <PLANT>0002</PLANT>
            <ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>11</ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>
        </row>
        <row>
            <EVENT_ID>171</EVENT_ID>
            <LINE_NUMBER>0</LINE_NUMBER>
            <INVOICE_NUMBER>24645</INVOICE_NUMBER>
            <INVOICE_DATE>2015-02-28 00:00:00.0</INVOICE_DATE>
            <CURRENCY_CODE>USD</CURRENCY_CODE>
            <TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>999999</TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>
            <RO_NUMBER>103063</RO_NUMBER>
        </row>
        <row>
            <EVENT_ID>171</EVENT_ID>
            <LINE_NUMBER>1</LINE_NUMBER>
            <INVOICE_NUMBER>24645</INVOICE_NUMBER>
            <PLANT>0001</PLANT>
            <ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>11.47</ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>
        </row>
        <row>
            <EVENT_ID>171</EVENT_ID>
            <LINE_NUMBER>2</LINE_NUMBER>
            <INVOICE_NUMBER>24645</INVOICE_NUMBER>
            <PLANT>0001</PLANT>
            <ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>11.53</ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>
        </row>
    </ns:MT_ActualCosts>


My requested Target Structure should be something like this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I need to group under the Header segments RecordLine Segments of the same `EVENT_ID`.

Currently my XSLT can't create the needed structure.
this is my XSLT:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ns0="http://percite:scmaster/actual_costs">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="\\palnt03\palramnet-redirect$\IL-Users\My-Documents\nimrod_g\SAP\Projects\ScMaster\Finance\ActualCosts\development\xsd"> -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <ns0:MT_ActualCostPreNormalized>
    <xsl:for-each select= "ns0:MT_ActualCosts/row">
        <xsl:if test="LINE_NUMBER=0">
            <Header>
            <EVENT_ID><xsl:value-of select="EVENT_ID"></xsl:value-of>
            </EVENT_ID>
            <LINE_NUMBER>
            <xsl:value-of select="LINE_NUMBER"/>
            </LINE_NUMBER>
            <INVOICE_NUMBER>
                    <xsl:value-of select="INVOICE_NUMBER"/>
                    </INVOICE_NUMBER>
                    <CURRENCY_CODE>
                    <xsl:value-of select="CURRENCY_CODE"/>
                    </CURRENCY_CODE>
                    <TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>
                    <xsl:value-of select="TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET"/>
                    </TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>
                    <RO_NUMBER>
                    <xsl:value-of select="RO_NUMBER"/>
                    </RO_NUMBER>
                    <PLANT>
                    <xsl:value-of select="PLANT"/>
                    </PLANT>
                    <ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ALLOCATION_AMOUNT"/>
                    </ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>
            </Header>
        </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="LINE_NUMBER!=0">
                        <RecordLine>
                        <EVENT_ID><xsl:value-of select="EVENT_ID"></xsl:value-of>
                        </EVENT_ID>
                        <LINE_NUMBER>
                        <xsl:value-of select="LINE_NUMBER"/>
                        </LINE_NUMBER>
                        <INVOICE_NUMBER>
                        <xsl:value-of select="INVOICE_NUMBER"/>
                        </INVOICE_NUMBER>
                        <CURRENCY_CODE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="CURRENCY_CODE"/>
                        </CURRENCY_CODE>
                        <TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>
                        <xsl:value-of select="TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET"/>
                        </TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>
                        <RO_NUMBER>
                        <xsl:value-of select="RO_NUMBER"/>
                        </RO_NUMBER>
                        <PLANT>
                        <xsl:value-of select="PLANT"/>
                        </PLANT>
                        <ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ALLOCATION_AMOUNT"/>
                        </ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>
                        </RecordLine>
                </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ns0:MT_ActualCostPreNormalized>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet> 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yklFq.jpg
```

After implemenitng most of the code provided by Daniel Haley it seems like the solution is very near.
    Follwoing Martin's request I am adding here the current XSLT used+the current result XML.
    I will try and clerify my rules for the XSLT program:
     1.Each  record from the source XML should be analyzed as followed:
        if LINE_NUMBER = 0 then this is a header record and should produce a  segment**.(it shouldnt be added to the  segment )**
     - if LINE_NUMBER is > 0 and its EVENT_ID equals to the row produced the  segment the this is a RecordLine in the context of the same  segment and should open a  segment under the same ." 
    Few problems can be seen in the result xml:

1. The first 4 groups of Headers-RecordLines comes out nicley (EventIDs
   100 to 104) .but on EVENT_ID 105 something went wrong. it can be see
   that the row with LINE_NUMBER=0 created a Header segment but also
   added the data twice inside a record line. this is wrong result.
2. from this point on, all the records are getting messed up. 
   Currently I can't say why this happened.
   I have added part of the source XML (as image) as comming from our testing db.
   I have added part of the result XML (as image)Hope these notes will clearify the issue.

[Source XML part with event 105](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2DY9.jpg)

[Result XML part with event 105](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBkRd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using XSLT 2.0, you can use `xsl:for-each-group` ([see XSLT 2.0 grouping](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping)) to group by `EVENT_ID`.

Also, use an [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#copying) to handle all of the elements that don't need to change.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<ns:MT_ActualCosts xmlns:ns="http://percite:scmaster/actual_costs">
    <row>
        <EVENT_ID>106</EVENT_ID>
        <LINE_NUMBER>0</LINE_NUMBER>
        <INVOICE_NUMBER>9999</INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <INVOICE_DATE>2015-02-09 00:00:00.0</INVOICE_DATE>
        <CURRENCY_CODE>USD</CURRENCY_CODE>
        <TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>0001</TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>
        <RO_NUMBER>102808</RO_NUMBER>
    </row>
    <row>
        <EVENT_ID>106</EVENT_ID>
        <LINE_NUMBER>1</LINE_NUMBER>
        <INVOICE_NUMBER>24444</INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <PLANT>0003</PLANT>
        <ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>122</ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>
    </row>
    <row>
        <EVENT_ID>109</EVENT_ID>
        <LINE_NUMBER>0</LINE_NUMBER>
        <INVOICE_NUMBER>24458</INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <INVOICE_DATE>2015-02-09 00:00:00.0</INVOICE_DATE>
        <CURRENCY_CODE>USD</CURRENCY_CODE>
        <TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>0011</TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>
        <RO_NUMBER>102813</RO_NUMBER>
    </row>
    <row>
        <EVENT_ID>109</EVENT_ID>
        <LINE_NUMBER>1</LINE_NUMBER>
        <INVOICE_NUMBER>24458</INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <PLANT>0003</PLANT>
        <ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>11.1</ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>
    </row>
    <row>
        <EVENT_ID>108</EVENT_ID>
        <LINE_NUMBER>0</LINE_NUMBER>
        <INVOICE_NUMBER>24535</INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <INVOICE_DATE>2015-02-19 00:00:00.0</INVOICE_DATE>
        <CURRENCY_CODE>USD</CURRENCY_CODE>
        <TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>11</TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>
        <RO_NUMBER>102811</RO_NUMBER>
    </row>
    <row>
        <EVENT_ID>108</EVENT_ID>
        <LINE_NUMBER>1</LINE_NUMBER>
        <INVOICE_NUMBER>24535</INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <PLANT>0002</PLANT>
        <ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>11</ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>
    </row>
    <row>
        <EVENT_ID>171</EVENT_ID>
        <LINE_NUMBER>0</LINE_NUMBER>
        <INVOICE_NUMBER>24645</INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <INVOICE_DATE>2015-02-28 00:00:00.0</INVOICE_DATE>
        <CURRENCY_CODE>USD</CURRENCY_CODE>
        <TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>999999</TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>
        <RO_NUMBER>103063</RO_NUMBER>
    </row>
    <row>
        <EVENT_ID>171</EVENT_ID>
        <LINE_NUMBER>1</LINE_NUMBER>
        <INVOICE_NUMBER>24645</INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <PLANT>0001</PLANT>
        <ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>11.47</ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>
    </row>
    <row>
        <EVENT_ID>171</EVENT_ID>
        <LINE_NUMBER>2</LINE_NUMBER>
        <INVOICE_NUMBER>24645</INVOICE_NUMBER>
        <PLANT>0001</PLANT>
        <ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>11.53</ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>
    </row>
</ns:MT_ActualCosts>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:ns="http://percite:scmaster/actual_costs">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--Identity transform.-->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <ns:MT_ActualCostPreNormalized>
      <!--Group rows by EVENT_ID.-->
      <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="EVENT_ID">
        <!--Optional sort by EVENT_ID.-->
        <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        <Header>
          <!--Apply templates to the children of row's with a LINE_NUMBER of 0 
          followed by row's that have a LINE_NUMBER that isn't equal to 0.-->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[LINE_NUMBER=0]/*,
            current-group()[not(LINE_NUMBER=0)]">
            <!--Optional sort by LINE_NUMBER.-->
            <xsl:sort select="LINE_NUMBER"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </Header>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </ns:MT_ActualCostPreNormalized>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Because of the apply-templates, the only row elements matched 
  should be row's with a LINE_NUMBER > 0.-->
  <xsl:template match="row">
    <RecordLine>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </RecordLine>          
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<ns:MT_ActualCostPreNormalized xmlns:ns="http://percite:scmaster/actual_costs">
   <Header>
      <EVENT_ID>106</EVENT_ID>
      <LINE_NUMBER>0</LINE_NUMBER>
      <INVOICE_NUMBER>9999</INVOICE_NUMBER>
      <INVOICE_DATE>2015-02-09 00:00:00.0</INVOICE_DATE>
      <CURRENCY_CODE>USD</CURRENCY_CODE>
      <TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>0001</TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>
      <RO_NUMBER>102808</RO_NUMBER>
      <RecordLine>
         <EVENT_ID>106</EVENT_ID>
         <LINE_NUMBER>1</LINE_NUMBER>
         <INVOICE_NUMBER>24444</INVOICE_NUMBER>
         <PLANT>0003</PLANT>
         <ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>122</ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>
      </RecordLine>
   </Header>
   <Header>
      <EVENT_ID>108</EVENT_ID>
      <LINE_NUMBER>0</LINE_NUMBER>
      <INVOICE_NUMBER>24535</INVOICE_NUMBER>
      <INVOICE_DATE>2015-02-19 00:00:00.0</INVOICE_DATE>
      <CURRENCY_CODE>USD</CURRENCY_CODE>
      <TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>11</TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>
      <RO_NUMBER>102811</RO_NUMBER>
      <RecordLine>
         <EVENT_ID>108</EVENT_ID>
         <LINE_NUMBER>1</LINE_NUMBER>
         <INVOICE_NUMBER>24535</INVOICE_NUMBER>
         <PLANT>0002</PLANT>
         <ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>11</ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>
      </RecordLine>
   </Header>
   <Header>
      <EVENT_ID>109</EVENT_ID>
      <LINE_NUMBER>0</LINE_NUMBER>
      <INVOICE_NUMBER>24458</INVOICE_NUMBER>
      <INVOICE_DATE>2015-02-09 00:00:00.0</INVOICE_DATE>
      <CURRENCY_CODE>USD</CURRENCY_CODE>
      <TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>0011</TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>
      <RO_NUMBER>102813</RO_NUMBER>
      <RecordLine>
         <EVENT_ID>109</EVENT_ID>
         <LINE_NUMBER>1</LINE_NUMBER>
         <INVOICE_NUMBER>24458</INVOICE_NUMBER>
         <PLANT>0003</PLANT>
         <ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>11.1</ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>
      </RecordLine>
   </Header>
   <Header>
      <EVENT_ID>171</EVENT_ID>
      <LINE_NUMBER>0</LINE_NUMBER>
      <INVOICE_NUMBER>24645</INVOICE_NUMBER>
      <INVOICE_DATE>2015-02-28 00:00:00.0</INVOICE_DATE>
      <CURRENCY_CODE>USD</CURRENCY_CODE>
      <TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>999999</TOTAL_AMOUNT_NET>
      <RO_NUMBER>103063</RO_NUMBER>
      <RecordLine>
         <EVENT_ID>171</EVENT_ID>
         <LINE_NUMBER>1</LINE_NUMBER>
         <INVOICE_NUMBER>24645</INVOICE_NUMBER>
         <PLANT>0001</PLANT>
         <ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>11.47</ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>
      </RecordLine>
      <RecordLine>
         <EVENT_ID>171</EVENT_ID>
         <LINE_NUMBER>2</LINE_NUMBER>
         <INVOICE_NUMBER>24645</INVOICE_NUMBER>
         <PLANT>0001</PLANT>
         <ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>11.53</ALLOCATION_AMOUNT>
      </RecordLine>
   </Header>
</ns:MT_ActualCostPreNormalized>
```

<kbd>[Working Example](http://xsltransform.net/bFN1y9A)</kbd>

Comment: Daniel,Thanks for your solution. Seems like somewhere down the result the data begins to scramble for some reason. look at EVENT_ID = 105.

Answer (score 2):

As you write that you want to group elements I guess as a starting point you can use `for-each-group` instead of `for-each`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
xmlns:ns0="http://percite:scmaster/actual_costs">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <ns0:MT_ActualCostPreNormalized>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="EVENT_ID">
              <Header>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="EVENT_ID, LINE_NUMBER, current-group()"/>
              </Header>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </ns0:MT_ActualCostPreNormalized>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <RecordLine>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </RecordLine>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

You can list further elements you want to have below `Header` in the `apply-templates`.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your code.
How can I eliminate rows with LINE_NUMBER=0 as they are representing header segments which I don’t want to include in my RecordLines. (to maintain data integrity)

Comment: If you don't want to group them at all change `<xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="EVENT_ID">` to `<xsl:for-each-group select="row[not(LINE_NUMBER = 0)]" group-by="EVENT_ID">`. If you want to group them by EVENT_ID but don't want to include them in the `Header` element as `RecordLine`, then change `<xsl:apply-templates select="EVENT_ID, LINE_NUMBER, current-group()"/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="EVENT_ID, LINE_NUMBER, current-group()[not(LINE_NUMBER = 0)]"/>`

Comment: Hi,I believe the casue for the duplication is the 
<xsl:template match="row">
        <RecordLine>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </RecordLine>
    </xsl:template>
it duplicates the LINE_NUMBER "0" that represents the headers into the RecordLine as well.

Comment: In that case you can change the inner `<xsl:apply-templates/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="* except LINE_NUMBER"/>` or `<xsl:apply-templates select="* except LINE_NUMBER[. = 0]"/>`. If you still have problems then consider to edit your question and show us the result you want as a code sample, I am afraid the screen shot does not suffice to tell us which elements you want to include and which not.

Comment: Martin,
I tried my best ( at the fourm limitations) to add some mroe data on my case.hope this can help...